# https Dynamic URL without an index.php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am using wordpress with the whmcs-bridge plugin... the problem is that my links are not seo friendly... the whmcs-bridge plugin produces urls like this

```
https://mysite.com/whmcs-bridge/?ccce=cart&a=add&pid=1
```

notice there is no index.php? just the ?...

I have tried mod rewrite tools, htaccess advise and all other methods provided by the net. this is what i was able to produce thus far

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /ccce/(.*)/a/(.*)/pid/(.*)\.html ?ccce=$1&a=$2&pid=$3
```

with the safe url being
    mysite.com/ccce/cart/a/add/pid/1.html

its a no go...

I have placed the code in the htaccess root directory as well as created a whmcs-bridge folder with its own htaccess directives... still no go... any help would greatly be appreciated.

again this a httpS url without the call for the index.php and there are 3 parameters to call.
    ccce = cart
    a = add
    pid = 1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this to work as the bridge re writes urls in the script

```
$tmp=explode('://',cc_whmcs_bridge_url(),2);
    $tmp2=explode('/',$tmp[1],2);
    $sub=str_replace($tmp[0].'://'.$tmp2[0],'',cc_whmcs_bridge_url()).'/';
    $secure='&sec=1';
```

For example